# Error: "Cannot invoke String() on the primitive type float " on quadratic formula?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error `"Cannot invoke String() on the primitive type float"` on my first attempt at an android app:

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void calculate(View v){
        EditText number1text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
        EditText number2text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.b);
        EditText number3text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
        Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString()) , 
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString()), 
        num3 = Integer.parseInt(number3text.getText().toString());
        if ((num2 ^ 2) - (4*num1*num3) < 0){
            break;
        }

        float ans = (float) ((-(num2)- Math.sqrt(num2^2 - (4*num1*num3)))/2*num1);

        float ans2 = (float) ((-(num2)+ Math.sqrt(num2^2 - (4*num1*num3)))/2*num1);


        TextView answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        answer.setText("The Answer is: " + ans.toString());
        TextView answer2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans2);
        answer.setText("The Answer is: " + ans2.toString());

    }


    private TextView getText(String string) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The error occurs when I try to call `ans.toString()` and `ans2.toString()`.

Comment: Hey there, I just wanted to point out that you should use `num2*num2` rather than `^` since that is for XOR and not exponentiation. I also think that it is worth noting that you could, if you wanted to, have the answer come out to be in a + b _i_ form in the case that the discriminant is negative.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call `toString` (or any method) on any primitive type, such as `float`.  However, `String` conversion will convert it to a `String` for you with the `+` operator anyway.

```
answer.setText("The Answer is: " + ans);
```

If you need more control over the display format, you can use a `DecimalFormat`.

Additionally, this expression doesn't do what you think it does.

```
(num2 ^ 2)
```

The `^` operator is a bitwise-XOR in Java, not exponentiation.  Use:

```
num2 * num2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Float.toString(ans)` and `Float.toString(ans2)`. You can't perform `.toString` (or any instance method) on primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Just leave the code as below:

```
 answer.setText("The Answer is: " + ans2);
```

And similar to next one.

You cannot use `toString()` or any methods on primitive data types.

**Remember:** Methods are defined inside a class. So to use method, the variable must first be an object.

**Edited:**

You can also do

```
 answer.setText("The Answer is: " + String.valueOf(ans2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `toString()` on a primtive. You can use [`String.valueOf(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28float%29)

```
String str = String.valueOf(ans);
String str2 = String.valueOf(ans2);
```

Also, Java does not perform exponentiation with `^` (it's bitwise xor)

```
if ((Math.pow(num2, 2)) - (4*num1*num3) < 0){
```