# can resolve error in very basic android code

Tags: java, android

this is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.calc.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText no1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
private EditText no2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
private EditText out=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void add(View view){
    float output=Float.parseFloat(out.getText().toString());
    float no1Value = Float.parseFloat(no1.getText().toString());
    float no2Value = Float.parseFloat(no2.getText().toString());
    float ans=Calc.Add(no1Value, no2Value);
    output.setText(String.valueOf(Calc.Add(no1Value, no2Value)));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is my Calc.java

```
package com.calc.calculator;

public class Calc {

public static float Add(float no1,float no2){
    return(no1+no2);
}

}
```

i am trying to make a very simple app that calculates the sum of two nos. but it shows an error in Mainactivity.java at line 35 which is

```
output.setText(String.valueOf(Calc.Add(no1Value, no2Value)));
```

it says Cannot invoke setText(String) on the primitive data type float

i am new to android development and i am stuck on this very beginner problem.
pls help :D

Comment: output is defined as a **float** (`float output=Float.parseFloat(out.getText().toString());`). You can't pass a **string** to it. It doesn't have the `setText()` method.

Comment: Please check this answer: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533870/error-cannot-invoke-string-on-the-primitive-type-float-on-quadratic-formul)

Comment: That's a typo neither `java` nor `android` error. Better check your code instead of putting an answer. You should have written `out.setText(String.valueOf(Calc.Add(no1Value, no2Value)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert output of type `float` to a `String`

change output to type `String`

or `String output_ = "" + output;`

and then

`out.setText(output_);`

Comment: @SanilKhurana view Edit

Comment: i tried that now i am getting settext is undefeined for string

Comment: @SanilKhurana what are you trying to set the text of

Comment: i am trying to make the output editview show the result of the function Add in Calc.java

Comment: that worked. your previous edit was correct too, i just made a typo and when i saw the error icon i pressed ctrl+z thinking that the error was not resolved.srry about that. and thnx for d help :D